# how to order arrangements based on a condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dictionary, filter

I have a structure in which the number of arrangements can vary:

```
array1 = [
{local: {id: 1, name: 'local1'}},
{local: {id: 2, name: 'local2'}},
{local: {id: 3, name: 'local3'}},
{local: {id: 4, name: 'local4'}},
{local: {id: 5, name: 'local5'}}
];

array2 = [
{local: {id: 1, name: 'local1'}},
{local: {id: 3, name: 'local3'}},
{local: {id: 3, name: 'local4'}},
{local: {id: 3, name: 'local5'}},
];

array3 = [
{local: {id: 1, name: 'local1'}},
{local: {id: 3, name: 'local2'}},
{local: {id: 3, name: 'local3'}},
{local: {id: 3, name: 'local5'}},
];
```

I need to create a new array from these, in which this new array is ordered first by the ids that are repeated in all the arrays and then the ones that are not repeated, should be something like this:

```
newArray = [
    {local: {id: 1, name: 'local1'}},
    {local: {id: 3, name: 'local3'}},
    {local: {id: 5, name: 'local5'}},
    {local: {id: 2, name: 'local2'}},
    {local: {id: 4, name: 'local4'}}
  ]
```

Someone who can help me please!!

Comment: For the repeated id case, what element from all the arrays you are expecting to be pushed in the result array.

Comment: Would the value of name be the same for all similar ids?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you researched your problem? I don't see any code attempts in your question. While we're all eager to help, it's also important to note that Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Please show us what you've tried so far so that we can nodge you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Converting all the arrays to objects for fast searching.

```js
const array1 = [{
    local: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'local1'
    }
  },
  {
    local: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'local2'
    }
  },
  {
    local: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'local3'
    }
  },
  {
    local: {
      id: 4,
      name: 'local4'
    }
  },
  {
    local: {
      id: 5,
      name: 'local5'
    }
  }
];

const array2 = [{
    local: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'local1'
    }
  },
  {
    local: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'local3'
    }
  },
  {
    local: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'local4'
    }
  },
  {
    local: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'local5'
    }
  },
];

const array3 = [{
    local: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'local1'
    }
  },
  {
    local: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'local2'
    }
  },
  {
    local: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'local3'
    }
  },
  {
    local: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'local5'
    }
  },
];

const obj1 = array1.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.local.id] = item;
  return acc;
}, {});

const obj2 = array2.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.local.id] = item;
  return acc;
}, {});


const obj3 = array3.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.local.id] = item;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = {
  ...obj3,
  ...obj2,
  ...obj1
};

const output = [];
const temp = [];

for (let key in result) {
  if (obj1[key] && obj2[key] && obj3[key]) {
    output.push(result[key]);
  } else temp.push(result[key]);
}

console.log([...output, ...temp]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this (may not be the optimum solution):

```js
/* Same Arrays as yours */ const array1=[{local:{id:1,name:"local1"}},{local:{id:2,name:"local2"}},{local:{id:3,name:"local3"}},{local:{id:4,name:"local4"}},{local:{id:5,name:"local5"}}],array2=[{local:{id:1,name:"local1"}},{local:{id:3,name:"local3"}},{local:{id:3,name:"local4"}},{local:{id:3,name:"local5"}}],array3=[{local:{id:1,name:"local1"}},{local:{id:3,name:"local2"}},{local:{id:3,name:"local3"}},{local:{id:3,name:"local5"}}];

function myFunc(arrays) {
  // All items, with duplicates
  const allItems = [].concat.apply([], arrays);
  // All IDs, without duplicates thanks to `Set`
  const allIDs = Array.from(
    allItems.reduce((set, item) => set.add(item.local.id), new Set())
  );
  
  // Helper function used for sorting
  const isInAllArrays = id => arrays.every(
    arr => arr.some(item => item.local.id === id)
  );
  // Sort the IDs based on whether they are in all arrays or not
  allIDs.sort((a, b) => {
    const _a = isInAllArrays(a), _b = isInAllArrays(b);
    if (_a !== _b) return _a ? -1 : 1;
    return 0;
  });
  // Map all IDs to the first element with this ID
  return allIDs.map(id => allItems.find(item => item.local.id === id));
}

const newArray = myFunc([array1, array2, array3]);

// Just for readability in the demo below
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray).split('},{').join('},\n{'));
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Traverse all arrays and build an object with keys as `id` and value include object and also maintain the frequency of occurrence  (count). 
2) Now, `Object.values` of above object and sort them based on 'count'.
You will get most frequent items at top.

```js
const sort = (...arrs) => {
  const all = {};
  arrs
    .flat()
    .forEach(
      (obj) =>
        (all[obj.local.id] =
          obj.local.id in all
            ? { ...all[obj.local.id], count: all[obj.local.id].count + 1 }
            : { ...obj, count: 1 })
    );
  return Object.values(all)
    .sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count)
    .map(({ count, ...rest }) => rest);
};

array1 = [
  { local: { id: 1, name: "local1" } },
  { local: { id: 2, name: "local2" } },
  { local: { id: 3, name: "local3" } },
  { local: { id: 4, name: "local4" } },
  { local: { id: 5, name: "local5" } },
];

array2 = [
  { local: { id: 1, name: "local1" } },
  { local: { id: 3, name: "local3" } },
  { local: { id: 3, name: "local4" } },
  { local: { id: 3, name: "local5" } },
];

array3 = [
  { local: { id: 1, name: "local1" } },
  { local: { id: 3, name: "local2" } },
  { local: { id: 3, name: "local3" } },
  { local: { id: 3, name: "local5" } },
];


console.log(sort(array1, array2, array3))
```